# Add item to admin panel - w/o plugin & theme

Tags: wp-admin, add-menu-page

I'd like to create a new page in the wp-admin panel. I know I should use the `add_menu_page()` function for that and I understand how it works.

I'm new to WP development, and would just like to know in which file I should put this function. The [doc](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_menu_page/) does not answer to my question, or I don't understand it.

I don't know if it's possible but I'd like this page to be part of neither the plugins nor the themes.

Thanks for your help

Comment: It HAS to be in either a plugin or a theme. Otherwise it is either (a) not included, therefore not going to work, or (b) part of WordPress core, which you should not modify as it will be overwritten every time WP is upgraded.

Comment: Modifying WordPress itself is a massive no no, never make changes in `wp-admin` or `wp-includes` to build your site, it'll all get undone on the next update. Fun story: Linkedin did this on an internal site, which meant they couldn't update and didn't get security fixes. A few years later they got hacked as a result and were fined millions for the data breach. If you're intimidated by the idea of making a plugin don't be, it's just a PHP file with a comment at the top

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as it gets registered before the `admin_menu` hook happens, it doesn't matter what file you put it in.  The important part is what hook you call your function on.  For simplicity sake you could put it in a themes `functions.php`.  If you want things to look a bit cleaner then put it in a php file named `admin-menu.php` (or whatever explanatory name you want) and `require_once` that file from `functions.php`

```
add_action('admin_menu', 'your_function_name');
function your_function_name() {
    add_menu_page(...)// add your menu page here

}
```

Comment: It has to be registered before the admin_menu action is fired though, so I don't know if I would say it doesn't matter as long as it is required.

Comment: Good point.  Edited for clarification.

Comment: thanks a lot for your answers! really helped me out